# Can't connect wordpress project to database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

I've setup a server at Digital Ocean. I've installed mysql and phpmyadmin and all that stuff on there, and made a database. On the server, there's a user besides 'root' called 'webcurator'. This user has a database with the same name. I've used the phpmyadmin login for the wp-config file.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'webcurator' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'webcurator' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' ); // Probably 'localhost'
```

I've checked everything I know. I can log into mysql directly using 'mysql -h localhost -u webcurator -p' and i've tried a lot of different combinations in the wp-config settings. But i'm still getting this wordpress error:

[image]

I'm out of options, hope someone has some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, at the database level for webcurator, select The Privileges tab - do you see "database-specific" under type for webcurator?

Comment: When I login phpmyadmin with webcurator I can't see the privileges tab. When I login with root, at the webcurator DB the privileges for webcurator are set to database-specific.

Comment: Does it also show "localhost" for webcurator under "Host"?

Comment: Yes, it says: webcurator, localhost, database-specific, all privileges

Comment: It seems like MySQL is running out of RAM and crashing. You could add swap and see if that helps (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04), or upgrade your droplet to the next plan so that there's more RAM available for MySQL.

Comment: I updated the droplet to 1GB of ram and this is the first and only project on the server. Unfortunately still no connection...

Comment: I suggest asking their support folks for assistance because this doesn't make any sense. Is there any chance the WordPress install is on a different server than the shell connection where you ran the `mysql...` command? You appear to be using the exact same host, username, and password to connect, so it should work. The only other thing I can think is that for some reason the configuration file you're editing might not be the right one. Try adding a new line like `die("Reading the correct configuration");` and see if that message is displayed. If not, there's a problem with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

login to mysql with root

mysql -u root -p yourpassword

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'webcurator'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as changing the DB_HOST so it was using the correct host and port in **wp-config.php**:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.01:3306');
```

Where 3306 was my default port for mysql